# How can I continue an interrupted compilation after an error occurred?

Tags: makefile, cmake

**After an error occurred because of a missing flag or incorrectly set environment variable, is it possible to *continue* compiling once the mistake has been fixed?**

I regularly use CMake and `make` to compile toolkits that take quite a while to compile and, also regularly, I accidentally set variables incorrectly in the process. Just now for example, I was attempting to include OpenInventor headers which on my machine are located in the directory `/Users/user/software/prod/coin/include/Inventor`.

I mistakenly passed

```
-DINVENTOR_INCLUDE_DIR=/Users/user/software/prod/coin/include/Inventor
```

rather than the correct

```
-DINVENTOR_INCLUDE_DIR=/Users/user/software/prod/coin/include
```

This only became an issue after 30 minutes when about 95% of the compilation was completed. Because I knew that reconfiguring using CMake would force a recompilation from scratch, I tried to add `-I/Users/user/software/prod/coin/include` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` in `CMakeCache.txt` but to no avail–it still recompiled from scratch. Since only a single source file actually includes the headers in question, it would be desirable if I could start compiling from the point where it exited with an error once the relevant path has been corrected. How can I do this and, as an aside, why does it force the compiler to start from scratch?

I'm using CMake version 3.11.1 and clang (Apple LLVM version 9.1.0) on macOS 10.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMake` does not need to recompile everything just because it regenerates its makefiles.  It will still perform normal make avoidance operations.  However CMake does track the compiler options used to build each target, so if you make a change in the compiler options for all the targets then they'll all need to be rebuilt.

If this compiler option is only needed for one target, you can add it to just that target an no others, with something like this:

```
set_property(SOURCE my_source.c APPEND PROPERTY
    COMPILE_FLAGS -I/foo/bar)
```

then it should only rebuild that one source file.

Answer (score 0):

CMake looks for files' "last modified" times to decide which files need recompilation. But if you change the input to CMake itself, then it needs to regenerate the Makefiles and therefore recompile everything. But still, one *hack* may be possible...

CMake stores information about the include directories and the libraries to be linked in various text files in the build directory. So one *hack* (not recommended, but works) can be to modify these text files.

In the particular example that you mentioned, the hack would be to search and replace all occurrences of `/Users/user/software/prod/coin/include/Inventor` with `/Users/user/software/prod/coin/include` in all the files of the build directory.

(As an aside, if you don't already know, you can use `make -j <n>` to build using multiple threads which can considerably decrease the build times.)